# Lines between the opening tag and closing tag

Tags: dreamweaver

Can you make **lines show up in Dreamweaver** between the opening tag and the closing tag ?

**Here is a screenshot(from Notepad++) as an example of what I mean:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't display line in Dreamweaver.